# MD5 gives different result between PHP and ash/OSX

Tags: php, md5, busybox, md5sum

I'm creating a hash on Busybox that I'm comparing with in a php script.

However results are anything but desired:

```
BusyBox v1.15.3 echo A|md5sum     bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef  -
MacBook-Air:~ $ echo A|md5        bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef
MacBook-Air:~ $ echo "A"|md5      bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef
[root@centos67 ~] echo "A"|md5sum bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef
.
PHP LAMP: echo md5("A");          7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
PHP MAMP: echo md5("A");          7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
```

*Additionally, googled [online md5 generating scripts](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+md5+generator)  always return the same result as the PHP ones above.*

Why is this happening?  What is (if any) the difference between md5 and md5sum, and if there's a difference, why the naming inconsistency between busybox and OSX?

How can I get PHP to generate the same hash my Busybox generates?  The other way around (make Busybox gerenate a PHP md5) is also ok, but it does have to work with my basic Busybox version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer was quite simple.

GNU `echo` always ends with a *newline*.

Two possible fixes:

```
BusyBox v1.15.3 echo -n A|md5sum     7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29  -
MacBook-Air:~ $ echo -n A|md5        7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
MacBook-Air:~ $ echo -n "A"|md5      7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
[root@centos67 ~] echo -n "A"|md5sum 7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
.
PHP LAMP: echo md5("A");             7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
PHP MAMP: echo md5("A");             7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
```

or

```
BusyBox v1.15.3 echo A|md5sum        bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef  -
MacBook-Air:~ $ echo A|md5           bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef
MacBook-Air:~ $ echo "A"|md5         bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef
[root@centos67 ~] echo "A"|md5sum    bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef
.
PHP LAMP: echo md5("A\n");           bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef
PHP MAMP: echo md5("A\n");           bf072e9119077b4e76437a93986787ef
```